# Internal memory on my Android is full: even after factory reset (and no apps downloaded). What can I do?

Tags: insufficient-memory, ram

I can download apps of up to 16 MB or so but that's about it. I can't free up enough space to download a single "big" app like Facebook. And it's weird because my phone was able to download this app (and many more) the first time I used it.

So I'm guessing there must be junk files on my internal memory, but I've done EVERYTHING in my hands to find them: deleted cache; logcat; even apps like "Clean Master".

Is there anything I can do to at least download Facebook and nothing else? I don't want to buy a new one just to use that app. My device isn't rooted by the way.

EDIT: Sorry for adding a reply down there. I asked the question as a guest and then realized I couldn't logged as said guest again to comment on my post.

If it helps, running the app "DiskUsage", I get this info:

Out of 186.4 MB of internal memory: 
132.8 MB appear to be free; 32 MB are taken by the system data; and 21.6 by apps (they're all system apks that take up the space: Google Play 9.05 MB; Maps 3.01 MB; Gmail 2.26 MB; etc.)

Comment: What device? Upload a screenshot of your "Storage" tab in your settings.

Comment: You need *at least* twice the amount of the size of the app of free space in order to download and install an app. Facebook is about 35 MB large, that means you need 70 MB of free space only to install the app (ignoring the space that is needed later for data)

Comment: @GiantTree: It's just I have more than Facebook could need... around 120 MB seems enough if you ask me (around four times the size!). Though my phone used to display an "insufficient space" notification with 80 MB or so way before I did the factory reset, so maybe it's not those 120 MB are really available. Do you know how I could find out?

Comment: @AaronGillion: It's an old phone, a Samsung Galaxy GT-I5500L. Internal phone storage says 118 MB available (I think the whole memory is about 180 MB, very little).

Comment: Please see this new article 2017/02/10 [10 most useless apps and games for Android](http://www.androidauthority.com/most-useless-apps-android-749163). Most prominent, but specifically named in the list: Clean Master (along with quote-Booster apps, Anti-Virus apps, and Task Killers-unquote)